# Can one SELECT retrieve an arbitrary number of columns, then union a single-column followed by nulls

Tags: oracle, union

I am trying to UNION a couple of dissimilar-width SELECTs into a single result.  In Oracle standard SQL but no PL/SQL is allowed due to my lack of permissions.  The query is roughly like below (with notes).

```
1  SELECT * FROM [FOO] WHERE ROWNUM=1
2  UNION
3  SELECT COUNT(*), {n-1 null columns} FROM [FOO]
```

The source table `[FOO]` is substituted into the query at run-time, its column count and column labels are arbitrary and unknown in advance, but line #1 of the query just grabs them all.

In line #3 of the query, I wish to fill the first column with an integer row-count of the `[FOO]` table, followed by as many Null columns as necessary (table width minus 1) to fill out the correct number of columns yielded by line #1.  The result ideally will look like this.

[image: A 3x3 matrix having labels, content, and row 3 is an integer]

I think the tricky part of this is making it work for arbitrary widths or column labels from line #1.  Is there an approach other than the UNION hypothesis above?  Thank you all.

Comment: It would be much simpler to add the row count as an extra column rather than as an extra row. Could whatever is calling this work with that approach?

Comment: The requirement doesn't even make sense in general - if the count is to be UNION-ed into the first column, this means what you want to do will only work if the first column is compatible with the `NUMBER` data type.

Comment: Also, obviously, this can't work in a standard SQL statement; SQL requires the table names (and column names) to be known when you write the code. Otherwise you will need dynamic SQL - an advanced topic, and an approach with many drawbacks (generally not recommended).

Comment: Good point Alex, but I have so far been stymied because you can't mix data columns with aggregate functions.  Mathguy's point on typing is correct too, unless you cast to a string maybe.  However my requirement IS to work on arbitrary data--the table names and columns aren't known in advance, so maybe unusual but is part of my setup.  Thanks you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a comment on the suggestion to add a column rather than a row:

> I have so far been stymied because you can't mix data columns with aggregate functions

You can use the analytic equivalents though. This uses the HR sample schema's `departments` table which has 27 rows, but just substitute any table name - you need to keep the table alias though, so you can do `t.*`:

```
select count(*) over (partition by null) as total_count,
  t.*
from departments t;

TOTAL_COUNT DEPARTMENT_ID DEPARTMENT_NAME                MANAGER_ID LOCATION_ID
----------- ------------- ------------------------------ ---------- -----------
         27            10 Administration                        200        1700
         27            20 Marketing                             201        1800
         27            30 Purchasing                            114        1700
...
```

You can't just add a `rownum` check though, as it will only count the rows in the result set:

```
select count(*) over (partition by null) as total_count,
  t.*
from departments t
where rownum = 1;

TOTAL_COUNT DEPARTMENT_ID DEPARTMENT_NAME                MANAGER_ID LOCATION_ID
----------- ------------- ------------------------------ ---------- -----------
          1            10 Administration                        200        1700
```

so you'd need to use a subquery:

```
select *
from (
  select count(*) over (partition by null) as total_count,
    t.*
  from departments t
)
where rownum = 1;

TOTAL_COUNT DEPARTMENT_ID DEPARTMENT_NAME                MANAGER_ID LOCATION_ID
----------- ------------- ------------------------------ ---------- -----------
         27            10 Administration                        200        1700
```

Of course, you would normally use a subquery anyway so you can order the inner query before selecting a single row.